# Cron to run at 12:00 AM every day using Spring Scheduler

Tags: spring, cron, cronexpression, spring-scheduled

I am trying to execute a method every day for which I have added scheduler using Spring but its not getting executed.

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="logDeletionTask" method="deleteExpiredLogs" cron="0 0 0 * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduler pool-size="25" id="myScheduler"/>
```

Comment: Maybe your was running the code in machine or server with different time zone

Answer (score 1):

To me, the cron expression you are looking for is : `0 0 12 * * ?`

Here is a working sample for you :

applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <bean id="logDeletionTask" class="task.Task" />

    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="logDeletionTask" method="deleteExpiredLogs" cron="0 0 12 * * ?" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <task:scheduler pool-size="25" id="myScheduler"/>
</beans>
```

Task bean :

```
package task;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Task {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void deleteExpiredLogs() {
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this expression will schedule job at 12PM.

Comment: The third part of the expression is the hour, which is supposed to something from 0 to 23 (0 being 12 PM). If you want the job to be triggered at 12PM the correct expression is `0 0 0 * * ?` if you want it to be triggered at 12AM it's `0 0 12 * * ?`

Comment: There is something wrong in your answer if 0 correspond to 12 pm so 1  correspond to 1pm and 13 correspond to 1am and this can't be accepted to anyone